# Как быть с пунктуацией на стыке вводных слов?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Написал такую фразу:

*Во-первых, я не заметил, что это пример, а **потом, действительно,** в этом примере может быть и прошедшее время.*

И вот не знаю, правильно ли, что я выделил запятыми вводное слово *"действительно",* которое примыкает к другому вводному *"потом".* Как вообще быть в таких случаях, когда вводные слова идут друг за другом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да здесь и выбирать-то не приходится. На основании чего можно опустить требуемую запятую? Два вводных подряд (допустим, хотя "а потом" не очевидно)? А что это за мотивация такая? Ни из буквы, ни из духа правил такого не следует. Насчет "духа": наоборот, оговаривается, что всякие однородные списки, перечисления и проч. запятых между собой требуют.

Так что я даже логику идеи отказаться от запятых между вводными не понимаю. 
Вряд ли что-то подобное есть в правилах.

Иное дело, если Вы (как автор) рассматриваете "а потом действительно" в качестве *единого вводного* оборота, но мне кажется тут такой подход более чем натянут.

Comment: Спасибо! Да мне и не хотелось отказываться, просто сомневался.)